# Rewrite rule not taking effect

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to place a rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file so that requests for

```
http://example.com/jbossas/jboss-configuration
```

are redirected to:

```
http://example.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration
```

So I have tried  adding this rule into the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^jbossas/jboss-configuration jboss-server/jboss-configuration [R=301,L]
```

but it didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^/jbossas/jboss-configuration jboss-server/jboss-configuration [R=301,L]
```

didn't work either.

Is the rule correct? Or do I need to request a Web server restart to my Provider for changes to take effect? Note, I'm running Joomla 3 Web site.

Comment: "it didn't work" - In what way did it not work? Did you get an error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? By itself, the directive you posted would likely result in a malformed redirect. Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine` directive? Please include your entire `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive then...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^jbossas/jboss-configuration jboss-server/jboss-configuration [R=301,L]
> ```

By itself, this directive would likely result in a malformed redirect, since the directory-prefix would be prefixed to the *relative* substitution string. For external redirects, the *substitution* string should start with a slash. However, this would also depend on whether you have a `RewriteBase` directive set, as this dictates the URL-path that is used, overriding the directory-prefix.

If you are not getting a redirect at all then it's likely that the directive has been put in the wrong place. An external redirect like this would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the Joomla front-controller.

Not also, that the above regex matches any URL-path that simply *starts* `/jbossas/jboss-configuration`, not the URL exactly - if that is an issue?

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/jbossas/jboss-configuration jboss-server/jboss-configuration [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> didn't work either.

This would only match if the directive was used in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context. In a server context, the `RewriteRule` directive matches against the full URL-path, including the slash prefix. In a *directory* (or `.htaccess`) context it matches against the URL-path less the directory-prefix, so no slash prefix.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jbossas/jboss-configuration$ /jboss-server/jboss-configuration [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteEngine` directive is not required if it is already present in the file. (It is more logical to have the `RewriteEngine` directive once at the very top, but that is not required.)

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - only after you have confirmed that it works OK. This is to avoid the browser caching erroneous redirects whilst testing.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Apologizes for not being clear in my question. I didn't get any error but the rewrite rule was simply not effective.